# First login is slow in Windows 7 on every PC

Tags: windows-7, user-profile

Assuming this user never logged on to this PC before, it will take 1-2 minutes before desktop shows up. All subsequent logins are near instant. Another PC - same problem. Problem repeats if local profile for this user is deleted. Is there any remedy?

Additional information:

- We do not have any specific group policy settings, except for 4 options dealing with Windows update (I think it's 4 of them that we are using).
- All computers are members of the domain, users are logging in using a domain account.
- Profiles need to be deleted in the rare case they become corrupted. Don't ask me why - ask Microsoft.

Comment: Don't delete the local profiles?

Comment: You don't provide nearly enough information to answer this, is the PC a member of a domain, what sorts of group policies are being applied, etc...

Comment: So, assuming that "near instant" isn't going to happen for the first login, as that's only happening on subsequent logins *because* of the work being done in the "1-2 minutes" of the first login, what time would you consider acceptable for a first login, how have you arrived at that and what troubleshooting have you done already to find delays yourself? No there isn't a "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\MAKE_COMPUTER_LOG_IN_QUICKER" registry key that we all know about and you don't.

Comment: @ErnieTheGeek: replacement of the PC usually deletes all the local accounts. With many number of PCs and frequent change of hardware, this issue is inevitable.
Cheekaleak: sorry about that, I updated the question with new information.
DJ Pon3: thanks for your positive attitude and enormous help in figuring this out. You really made my day.

Answer (score 11):

Upon the first login, the profile must be created. This takes longer than subsequent logins. Also, user GPOs must be downloaded and applied from the DCs. The length of this creation and GPO application process can take some time depending on GPO and local policy, but 1-2 minutes doesn't sound unreasonable. I'd hardly consider this a "slow" login.

Comment: Assume there is nearly nothing to be applied, as we don't have any specific complex GPO, except for 4 options regarding windows update policy. I still can't believe why it would take that long. And it's definitely annoying on i7-2600 and 8-16GB of memory.

Comment: What you're describing is completely normal. There's also user settings in the default domain policy that are applied, and those few GPOs that are applied still take some time. Seriously, 1-2 minutes is not a long time, especially when it's only during the first login.

Comment: 1-2 minutes can become 5 when the collegue says "yeah, it's taking long, so I'll go grab a coffee", somebody stops them for a talk on the way back - it becomes 15 or half an hour - you decide to come back later etc. - that's how it can make a difference. Why would even first login matter? Imagine another person says "Hmm, it does not work under your account, let's try mine? Hmm, still does not work, let's try my another one" (with higher privileges). Even if it's only 1 minute. What if you had 100 PCs and 100 people? That's 10000 minutes, or 20 x 8-hour man-days. Then you start counting.

Comment: First of all, this is **only** during the first logon, not every time. If the only time you waste man hours in a day is on a 1 min logon, then you've got the most efficient company ever. Don't worry about it. It's one minute.  Second of all, think of all of the lost man hours if you weren't centrally managing everything. That's the trade off. I'm sorry that you don't like the answer, but **it's completely normal**. If you have an issue with it, you'll need to contact Microsoft and request that they speed up new profile creation. It's literally a non-issue for everyone else on the planet.

Comment: You got all good points here, @MD. Yes, there are many other ways to waste man-hours, and most of those are beyond my control. Just wanted to improve something I thought was easy to fix. If everybody's is okay with that, shame on Microsoft, because I personally think it is not okay. My code does not work like that. Not your fault of course, so probably I'll mark your answer as correct, if troubleshooting steps suggested by Helge Klein do not provide any useful information.

Comment: For what it's worth, Win8 has even faster profile load times than Win7. Too bad it's got that hideous interface, they did make quite a few improvements too.

Comment: For reference, in Windows 2012 login of a new domain account takes under 2 seconds. This is the kind of performance I would expect from Windows 7.

Answer (score -3):

1-2 minues is way too long if nothing much happens (massive GPOs etc.). Unfortunately there is no easy way to troubleshoot such slow logons - the delay might be network-related, or something completely different. What you can do:

- Trace what happens on the machine while logging on with Sysinternals Process Monitor
- Trace what happens on the network (use whatever network tracing tool is available to you, Microsoft Network Monitor will do just fine)

Comment: This would be interesting to try. Is there anything specific I am looking for with Process Monitor? With no filter I expect several hundred thousand of events logged when I am back, and most of those do not make much sense to me.

Comment: Did you read the question? The 1-2 min is **only** during the first logon during profile creation. It's not like it's every time. In fact, the op says that it's almost instant after the initial logon.

Comment: If you don't know something is impossible, you have a much higher chance of succeeding in it. I would rather attempt to troubleshoot and fail to find a problem, than admit I did not even try it.